# regex to prevent things like .png .jpg in emails efficient

Tags: java, regex

I have a java regex that parses the body of messages to search for email addresses.  The issue I have been having with it is that if there is some random text in the email like `<img567AB@JGB6.jpg> is attached!`, so it's essentially grabbing anything with the `@`. I plan on using a negative lookahead like `(?!png|jpg)`. Anyone know of a more efficient way?

this is the regex

`(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\])`

Comment: What is the regex? `@\w+`? Try `\B@\w+`

Comment: http://emailregex.com/

Comment: Please update the question with the regex and requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew – how does that help? `\B` says "no word boundary" and therefore `user@example.com` won't match `\B@\w+`

Comment: I'd use a negative lookaround. Depending on how your text is anchored, it might be best to look behind after the end of the email rather than to look forward.  The list of extensions you want to ban is probably smaller than the list of TLDs you want to accept, though there's also overlap, like [.py](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.py) (Python vs Paraguay) or the new [.zip TLD](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/zip.html) (what a horrible idea!)

Comment: added regex from comments